# I was following Computer Graphics from Scratch -- Getting distorted spheres

Tags: c++, graphics, cg

So I just started learning graphics programming, and got suggested https://gabrielgambetta.com/computer-graphics-from-scratch/ . The explanations are super good, but it provides pseudocode for the reader to implement. I am doing it in cpp (my first project), and am getting distroted spheres. I don't see any problem (maybe something related to doubles etc).

Also this book doesn't talk about how to get image output (just the logic), but thankfully I read the first parts of "Ray tracing in one weekend" book, which introduced me to the programming constructs to make it happen.

https://github.com/mesahilgautam/computer-graphics-from-scratch/tree/main/02-basic-ray-tracing Here's the source code.

I tried it multiple times, but got the same results.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3yfkrDT is what I am getting, and https://gabrielgambetta.com/computer-graphics-from-scratch/images/raytracer-01.png is what it was supposed to be.

Comment: Probably not the best site to ask this on. SO works best for small questions with code fitting into the question box, nobody wants to download a whole repo and debug it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes I realized that. Also I asked it on IRC #C++-General and as people said, I should debug my own code. Some maths error probably. I was trying to step through, but that doesn't work, I have to do it on paper and pen

Comment: Side note you should not put all your definitions (implementations) in header files

Comment: @PepijnKramer Thanks for that. This is my first project, I will improve on it.

Comment: https://github.com/mesahilgautam/computer-graphics Updated link just in case someone finds that folder deleted

Comment: You mean also your first project using C++?

Comment: @PepijnKramer No, I contribute to libreoffice in my freetime, so got some experience from there, on how to name variables, refactoring stuff etc. But first standalone selfwritten project.